# Picking/Selecting in an association

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

suppose I have 2 associations

```
t1=<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
```

and

```
t2=<|"a" -> x, "a1" -> x^2, "b0" -> x^3, "b" -> x^4, "b1" -> x^5, 
 "c" -> x^6, "c1" -> x^7, "c2" -> x^8, "d" -> x^9|>
```

How can I from t2 select those elements that are in t1? 
The output would look like:

```
<|"a" -> x, "b" -> x^4,"c" -> x^6, "d" -> x^9|>
```

I tried pick as `Pick[t2,t1]` yet it returns an empty sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
KeyIntersection[{t1, t2}][[2]]
```

> <|"a" -> x, "b" -> x^4, "c" -> x^6, "d" -> x^9|>

or

```
KeyTake[t2, Keys[t1]]
```

> <|"a" -> x, "b" -> x^4, "c" -> x^6, "d" -> x^9|>

Answer (score 8):

```
Query[Keys[t1]]@t2
```

> <|"a" -> x, "b" -> x^4, "c" -> x^6, "d" -> x^9|>

```
t2[[Keys @ t1]]
```

> <|"a" -> x, "b" -> x^4, "c" -> x^6, "d" -> x^9|>

```
KeySelect[t2, AssociationThread[Keys[t1] -> True]] (* or *)
KeySelect[t2, MemberQ[Keys[t1], #] &]
```

> <|"a" -> x, "b" -> x^4, "c" -> x^6, "d" -> x^9|>